Webview ios - Camera is opening in full screen even when allowsInlineMediaPlayback is true
Context: Trying to open camera in iOS(iPhone) app's WebView using mediaStream APIs, but it is opening camera in full screen mode rather than in the expected fixed width, height.
Flow: iOS application's WebView is loading opening React Application through secured(https) URL.
Question/Query: Can someone please help identify/suggest what might be the issue here?
Device used: iPhone 8, version - 16.6
PS: Please let me know in case any more information is required from my side.
WebView Configuration instance has following attribute set to True
 allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
const videoEl = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLVideoElement>;
const canvasEl = useRef() as MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;

<video
    // controls
    autoPlay
    playsInline
    muted
    loop
    preload="auto"
    width={window.screen.width.toString()}
    height={(window.screen.height * 0.5).toString()}
    ref={videoEl} />
<canvas
    style={{ opacity: 0 }}
    ref={canvasEl} />```

Callback code below to load video on launch of Component(useEffect() hook):

const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        facingMode: 'environment',
        width: window.screen.width,
        height: (window.screen.height * 0.5)
    }
}

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
video.srcObject = stream;
video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
    const { clientLeft, clientTop } = video
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    canvas.style.left = clientLeft.toString();
    canvas.style.top = clientTop.toString();
    canvas.setAttribute('width', window.screen.width.toString());
    canvas.setAttribute('height', (window.screen.height * 0.5).toString());
    video.play();
}

